# How to force TestNG create new instance of test class for each method if run mode is parallel="methods"

Tags: java, selenium, testng

How to force TestNG create new instance of test class for each method if run mode is `parallel="methods"`?

JUnit does it automatically but TestNG reuses same instance between methods.

Is there any option to change this behavior?

I'm running selenium tests and create webdriver in `@BeforeMethod` method and store it to class variable to use it in test methods and clos on `@AfterMethod`.

And I want to have ability to run methods of one test class in parallel without sharing webdriver.

Comment: You can achieve the effect you want by simply assigning your fields in the constructor.

Comment: That wouldn't work--the constructor only gets called once.

Comment: Managing driver using `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` is not a good idea. I would suggest to use TestNG with [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) which takes care of driver management and other black-box testing needs utilizing all features of TestNG in best efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to force testng to do that.  A solution is to set webdriver instance to a threadlocal variable.  What this would help doing is, it would create one webdriver object per thread, if u do a get on the variable, it. Would give u that thread's object only.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Factory](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories)

From [javadoc](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Factory.html):

```
Marks a method as a factory that returns objects that will be used by TestNG as Test classes. The method must return Object[].
```

Answer (score -1):

I've used TestNG to run multiple selenium webdriver tests in parallel.  To set up a new WebDriver for each method, use the @DataProvider [annotation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) and its associated attribute in the @Test annotation.