# One instance per test in TestNG without Factory?

Tags: testng

(This is a more special case than [How to force TestNG create new instance of test class for each method if run mode is parallel="methods"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15632854/499922))

I have a parametrized test that has 170k entries in the data provider. If I use a factory (as suggested in the question above), it will get stuck in `org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.sortMethods` building a map that is simply too big.

Is there anything I can do apart from manually creating the instances and wiring the data in?