# force TestNG to create new instance for every method test

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, testng

According to these links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056622/1623597 https://stackoverflow.com/a/15640575/1623597 
TestNG doesn't create new instance on every method test.

I have spring boot application. I need to write integration tests (Controller, service, Repositories). Sometimes to create new test case I need some entities in DB. To forget about any predefined entities in db, I decided to mock repository layer. I've just implemented ApplicationContextInitializer that finds all  JPA Repositoryies in classpath and adds theirs mocks to spring context.

I got new problem that my mocks are created once per one ControllerTest (that extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests). Tested context creates only once, and mock instances are the same for all methods. Now, I have

```
//All repos are mocked via implementation of ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericWebApplicationContext>
// and added to spring context by
//applicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(beanName, mock(beanClass));   //beanClass in our case is StudentRepository.class
@Autowired
StudentRepository studentRepository;

//real MyService implementation with autowired studentRepository mock
@Autowired
MyService mySevice;

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    mySevice.execute();     //it internally calls studentRepository.findOne(..); only one time
    verify(studentRepository).findOne(notNull(String.class));
}

//I want that studentRepository that autowired to mySevice was recreated(reset)
@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    mySevice.execute();     //it internally calls studentRepository.findOne(..); only one time
    verify(studentRepository, times(2)).findOne(notNull(String.class)); //I don't want to use times(2)
    //times(2) because studentRepository has already been invoked in test1() method

}

@Test
public void test3() throws Exception {
    mySevice.execute();     //it internally calls studentRepository.findOne(..); only one time
    verify(studentRepository, times(3)).findOne(notNull(String.class)); //I don't want to use times(3)
}
```

I need to increase times(N) for every next method.I understand that it's testng implementation, but I try to find good solution for me. For my services I use constructor autowiring and all fields are final.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to force testng to create new instance for every method test?
   Can I recreate spring context for every method test?
2. Can I create my custom proxy for every mocked repository and reset mocks in @BeforeMethod method via my proxy?

Comment: Did you already try to reset what you want in a @Before/AfterMethod?

Comment: I can't use this approach. The reason is that I could have 10 repositories, that are used in another 20 services. every of this service uses constructor autowiring and has final fields. Moreover I can't pass over all services and replace mocks in @Before/AfterMethod

Comment: How do you initialize `myService` ?

Comment: It's spring boot application. I've just added @_Service annotation. This service has @_Autowired before constructor (to autowire repos and so on)

Comment: Could you share the full test class ?

Comment: I can't share my big project with you. I've updated my source code. I hope it will by more clear. Don't you understand my problem? I can try to explain it one more time or answer on your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't need to create new repository mock instances in context, I just needed to reset their state.
I thought that Mockito.reset(mock) just create new instance and assign it to reference mock so far. **But it isn't true.** The real behavior of Mockito.reset is just clean current state for mock without creating new mock instance.

My solution:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

@Autowired
private List<Repository> mockedRepositories;

@BeforeMethod
public void before() {
    mockedRepositories.forEach(Mockito::reset);
}
```

This code autowire all repos that were mocked in ApplicationContextInitializer, and reset their state.
Now I can use verify() without times(2)

```
@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    mySevice.execute()
    verify(studentRepository).findOne(notNull(String.class));
}
```